# always failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'

Tags: javascript

Can anyone help me how to  delete  parameter 1. This is the error I always get:

> failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'

```js
<script src="assets/js/minicart.js"></script>
<script>
    counter = 1;
    $(".apply").click(function () {
        var root_container = document.getElementById("root-container");
        var container = document.createElement('div');
        var name_lists = document.getElementById('food-names');
        var price_lists = document.getElementById('food-prices');
        container.className="form-controll";
        container.id= counter;

        var input_name = document.createElement('input');
        var input_price = document.createElement('input');
        var button = document.createElement('button');
        var br = document.createElement('br')
        var input_total = document.createElement('input')

        container.className="modal-body row ";

        button.className  = "btn btn-danger delete1";
        button.name = "counter";
        button.type = "button";
        button.id = counter;
        button.onclick = "remove";
        button.appendChild(document.createTextNode("X"));
        counter++;

        input_name.value = $("#" + this.name ).html().trim();
        input_name.className = "text-center ";
        input_name.style.border = 'none';
        input_name.name= $("#" + this.name).html().trim();
        input_name.setAttribute("readonly", true)
        name_lists.value = name_lists.value + "=" + $("#" + this.name).html().trim();

        input_price.value = this.id.trim();
        input_price.className = "text-center";
        input_price.style.border = 'none';
        input_price.name=  this.id.trim();
        input_price.setAttribute("readonly", true)
        price_lists.value = price_lists.value + "=" + this.id.trim();

        container.appendChild(input_name);
        container.appendChild(input_price);
        container.appendChild(button);
        container.appendChild(br);

        root_container.appendChild(container);
    });

    $(document).on("click",'.delete1',function(){
        console.log('deleting node number -' + this.id-1);
        counter = -0;

        var root_container = document.getElementById("root-container");

        root_container.removeChild(root_container.childNodes[this.id]);

        for(i=0;i<counter.length;i++){
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I didnt went through all code its huge, what i saw is the code

```
var root_container = document.getElementById("root-container");

root_container.removeChild(root_container.childNodes[this.id]);
```

This code is fine and workable until the id is valid and unique and you have this.id, I think the issue is in this.id, what is `this.id` , I am sure the issue is there, hope it helps.
Quick tip use Chrome debugger tool and added a Event listener breakpoint on mouse click (Source tab > right side nav > Event listener breakpoints > Mouse > Click) check this box. your browser will break on this event and then check the this. 
Or alternatively you can console this, but the above way you could step to next and found the problem yourself, hope it helps